# How do I reduce null checks using Java 8 lambdas?

Tags: java, refactoring

I've been reading Uncle Bob's Clean Code and have read many articles on the use of Optionals whenever you are faced with returning a null in a Java method.  I'm currently refactoring my code and I just don't know how to optimize it with Optionals.  Can someone give me some pointers?

```
public UserLog selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);

    return logs.isEmpty() ? null : logs.get(0);
}

private List<UserLog> selectUserLogs(String sql, Object... args) throws DataException {
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, args);

    return rows.stream().map(this::toUserLogs)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private UserLog toUserLogs(Map<String, Object> row) {
    UserLog userLog = new UserLog("Steven Wozniak", 65, "Male");
    return userLog;
}

/**
* Below shows how selectById is being used in another class
*/
...
public void callingMethod() {
    if(starttime != null && FIVE_HOUR <= durationSinceStartTime() && 
            userLogDao.selectById(userid) != null &&
            userLogDao.selectById(userid).getStartTime() != null) {

        log.warn("Logs came in late");
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble optimizing the `selectById` method.  Since I'm doing a `Collector.toList()` in the `selectUserLogs` method, I can be sure that I will **ALWAYS** get a `List` back.  It could be an empty list, but never a `null`.

My initial attempt was:

```
public Optional<UserLog> selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);
    return Optional.ofNullable(logs.get(0));
    
}
```

However, I completely have no idea how I'm going to optimize the calling of this method and performing the null checks in the `callingMethod()`.  How would I re-write that so that it looks a tad more elegant?

Comment: Your question isn't really on topic for SO. It's inviting opinions, and does not relate to a specific problem. You might consider raising your question instead on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+optional). Alternatively, can you reframe your question to be more focused on a specific issue, without inviting opinions? Also, the person who designed and implemented `Optional` in Java posts answers here, so you might want to [read his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1441122+%5Bjava%5D+optional) for authoritative information.

Comment: FYI, asking _"Can someone give me some pointers?"_ is a red flag that your question lacks focus (for me at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code, I only see this improvement.
If you don't get `null` from `selectUserLogs` (and I also prefer an empty list than `null`), yo can update `selectById` and `callingMethod` to this:

```
public Optional<UserLog> selectById(String userid) throws DataException {
    List<UserLog> logs = selectUserLogs(SQL_SELECT_BY_ID, userid);

    return logs.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(logs.get(0));
}

public void callingMethod() {
    if (starttime != null && FIVE_HOUR <= durationSinceStartTime()) {
        userLogDao.selectById(userid)
                .map(UserLog::getStartTime)
                .ifPresent(startTime -> log.warn("Logs came in late"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `logs.isEmpty() ? Optional.emtpy() : Optional.of(logs.get(0))` line the same as `return Optional.ofNullable(logs.get(0));` ?

Comment: From my understanding, `selectById` returns `Optional<UserLog>`.  Why do we need a `flatMap` here?  Why wouldn't it be `map`?

Comment: No, in the first line, you are checking if the list logs is empty. If it is empty, you return an empty `Optional`, and if it's not empty, you return an `Optional` with the value `logs.get(0)`.

In the second line, you are directly trying to create an `Optional` from `logs.get(0)`. If the list logs is empty, calling `logs.get(0)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: About the map,  you're right it should be a `.map` instead of `.flatmap`. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave your `selectById` method exactly the same as you implemented; this is returning a null or a non null `UserLog` then in the calling method you could have something like below:

```
public void callingMethod() {
if(starttime != null && FIVE_HOUR <= durationSinceStartTime()) {
    Optional.ofNullable(userLogDao.selectById(userid)).ifPresent(
        userLog -> Optional.ofNullable(userLog.getStartTime()).
           ifPresent(startTime -> log.warn("Logs came in late")
    )}
}
```

If you make the `selectById` return an optional then the first Optional.ofNullable in the above code goes away as it is done already in the `selectById`

Also note that is a good practice to only call `userLogDao.selectById(userId)` once not only because you avoid some performance degradation but also because there is a real chance the two consecutive results might have different results and such you could face unexpected hard to explain behaviour.

The above code is just to give you an idea about how you can make null checks using Optional. I did not put it in my InteliJ so it might not even compile. However you should get the point.

Hope it helped.